# How do I ascertain client retention using SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which is a loan data containing the following columns:
**Row,  loanId, clientId,   DisbDate,   applicationDate,    approvalDate,   loanNumber, loanAmount, interestRate**

How do I  extract only clients that received their first loan in say, January 2018, and the number
of those clients that received/took out a loan in the following months of 2018.

**Note**: If a client took more than one loan in a month, they
should only be counted once.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Querying a database is a relatively straight-forward operation. Have you tried something on your own yet? I would do some research on the topic first.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I am an absolute beginner. I've been having problems coming up with the code. It's my hope that I'll be able to learn on the go, by reading the code to know what each line does and then taking it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*) as num_clients_jan,
       countif(max(DisbDate) >= date('2018-02-01')) as num_follows
from (select l.clientId, min(disbdate) as min_dsbdate, max(disbdate) as max_disbdate
      from loans l
     where DisbDate >= date('2018-01-01')
      group by l.clientId
      having min(DisbDate) < date('2018-02-01')
     ) x
```